# Mongoose pre or post save hook for updating the relations?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, relationship, middleware

Given the following Schemata with an n-to-m relation:

```
var CampaignSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    players: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Player'
    }]
});

var PlayerSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    campaigns: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Campaign'
    }]
});
```

When I create/update a Campaign document, the Player documents should be kept in sync with the players array of the Campaign model.

I saw a lot of examples in the web using the pre save hook, updating the corresponding players to include/exclude this campaign from their campaigns array.

However, I would expect the post save hook to be a better place for this kind of updates, as I can be sure that the model was saved successfully before updating the player documents.

So my question(s) would be:
is there anything I have to consider when choosing between a pre/post save hook to keep my relations in sync, or is it irrelevant and just a matter of taste?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after implementing a solution myself I ended up with circular dependency issues. Have a look on this [package](https://github.com/sabymike/mongoose-relationship), it solved my problem easily.